# Boxplot, skipping boxes whose median is outside the y range

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to draw a boxplot in R in which boxes with a median greater than the y limits are not drawn at all. Instead, a marker should be drawn at the top of the plot signifying that the value lies beyond the area of plot.

EDIT:
To clarify my goal: I have 20 boxes with a median in the range of [0,0.1] and two boxes with a median around 0.8. I would like to set my ylim=range(0,0.15) so that these two boxes are outside of the drawing area. But there should still be an indicator that there is a box at this position, e.g. by an arrow pointing upward. Also, using a log scale on the y axis is not a good option.

I have searched for a good solution, but I didn't find any. If there is no (semi-)automatic way, my idea was to take the results of boxplot, search for entries in the stats array that are too big, remove them, draw the reduced boxplot and add arrows by hand to the appropriate position. But I hope, that someone has a better idea.

Comment: You haven't searched so far just [google](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/boxplot.html) it, there you can start. Also have a look [ask].

Comment: @Llopis How does that link address the substantive point of the OP's question?

Comment: You must be specifying the `ylim` then, is this correct?

Comment: @GavinSimpson I think the Rlab package of the other Options section does it. But I haven't explored enough so maybe I'm wrong. Excuse me.

Comment: @Llopis It may do, but I don't know either and can't tell from that page if it does.